# Can't start MegaSync in Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: kubuntu, mega

I just installed Kubuntu 16.04 and I need to install MegaSync in it. I downloaded the installer megacmd-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb file frome https://mega.nz/sync and installed just clicking in on it. But after installation is done, I can't find the MegaSync app.

So I decided to reboot and there is still nothing. So then I installed it from a terminal just how is shown here: http://linuxpitstop.com/install-mega-megasync-cloud-file-storage-client-on-ubuntu-16-04-linux/ and the installation seems to be completed succesfully... but I still can't find the app! I looking for it in the Kubuntu search bar, but it simply isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You downloaded MEGAcmd [megacmd-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.04/amd64/megacmd-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb) terminal version. Package description below:

> **MEGA Command Line Interactive and Scriptable Application**
>   MEGAcmd provides non UI access to MEGA services. It intends to offer all the
>   functionality with your MEGA account via shell interaction. It
>   features 2 modes of interaction
>   * interactive. A shell to query your actions
>   * scriptable. A way to execute commands from a shell/a script/another program.

It has 50 separate non-GUI terminal executables named as `/usr/bin/mega-*`.

---

As far I can understand [MEGASync](https://mega.nz/sync) has two deb-packages with GUI on their site:

1. [megasync-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.04/amd64/megasync-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb) contains:

   - GUI executable `/usr/bin/megasync`
   - desktop application shortcut `/usr/share/applications/megasync.desktop`, which places MEGASync application icon in *Network* and *System* categories
2. [nautilus-megasync-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb](https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.04/amd64/nautilus-megasync-xUbuntu_16.04_amd64.deb) contains extension for Files/Nautilus (standard file-manager for GNOME desktop).

I tried to install both packages on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, its icon is shown normally on Unity and MATE.

Comment: THANK YOU! 

Ok, this is pretty weird, I remember perfectly I downloaded the app from nz/sync and even put the link in my question. Now I went to nz/cmd to see if maybe nz/sync and nz/cmd looks the same and I was in the wrong page... but nz/cmd it's diferent  and I would said I never went there. 

Now my question looks pretty dumb but I don't care. Maybe it can help others.

Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I have never used MEGA, and now I know that it exists and very functional. Thank you! And do not forget to accept my answer and vote up :)